# Standard matrix for linear transformation without using least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following question here:

> Let $W$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by $$\{(1,1,1),(-1,1,2)\}.$$ 
> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation given by the orthogonal projection onto $W$. Find the standard matrix of $T$.

I can do this $[T]=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\\ 1 & 2\\ \end{pmatrix}$

which yields $$[T]=\begin{pmatrix} 13/14 & 3/14 & -1/7\\  3/14 & 5/14 & 3/7\\ -1/7 & 3/7 & 5/7 ​\end{pmatrix}$$

This is correct but is there another way to do this with just the projection formula and using the standard basis vectors?

EDIT: Spelling.

Comment: What's "the project formula"?

Comment: Sorry. I just edited my post. I meant to say the projection formula where I project each of the standard coordinates onto the vectors in that subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also perform Gram-Schmidt on $\{(1,1,1),(−1,1,2)\}$ to obtain the orthonormal basis
$$v_1:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1, 1, 1), \quad v_2 := \frac{1}{\sqrt{42}}(-5, 1, 4).$$
Then,
$$T(x) = \operatorname{Proj}_{v_1}(x) + \operatorname{Proj}_{v_2}(x) = (x \cdot v_1)v_1 + (x \cdot v_2)v_2.$$
You can then build the standard matrix for $T$ in the usual way, by transforming standard basis vectors. For example,
\begin{align*}
T(e_1) &= (e_1 \cdot v_1)v_1 + (e_1 \cdot v_2)v_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}v_1 + \frac{-5}{\sqrt{42}}v_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{3}(1, 1, 1) - \frac{5}{42}(-5,1,4) \\
&= \left(\frac{13}{14}, \frac{3}{14}, \frac{-1}{7}\right),
\end{align*}
which agrees with your matrix so far. Computing the other columns should similarly agree with the given matrix.

Comment: Thank you! Why do I need the gram schmidt process though? Is it because the vectors given in $W$ are not orthogonal to each other? Furthermore, did you normalize the vectors we need the vectors to be in that $\textbf{direction}$?

Comment: Yes, we need the vectors to be orthogonal to each other, in order for the projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2\}$ to be the sum of the projections onto $\operatorname{span}\{v_1\}$ and $\operatorname{span}\{v_2\}$. It's not necessary for the vectors to be normalised, but doing so means we can use $(x \cdot v_i)v_i$ instead of $\frac{(x \cdot v_i)}{(v_i \cdot v_i)}v_i$. The direction of the vectors is not important, so feel free to replace $v_i$ with $-v_i$.

Comment: Thanks so you much for the conceptual understanding!

Answer (score 1):

You can always go with the definition of $[T]$, which means the first column of the matrix is equal to $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)$...

Comment: I agree with you, but that doesn't seem to be working. 

I would project and then subtract from the original vector right? So This should be the case:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2C0%2C0%29+-+%28%281%2C0%2C0%29+dot+%281%2C1%2C1%29%29%2F%28%281%2C1%2C1%29+dot+%281%2C1%2C1%29%29+%281%2C1%2C1%29+-+%28%281%2C0%2C0%29+dot+%28-1%2C1%2C2%29%29%2F%28%28-1%2C1%2C2%29+dot+%28-1%2C1%2C2%29%29+%28-1%2C1%2C2%29

but it's not matching what I should get.